# Missing Firefox icon in Installed Applications list

Tags: raspbian, pixel

I am running Raspbian/Pixel on a Pi 3, and have installed Firefox ESR (which I prefer to Chromium).  However, I haven't yet found any way of getting Firefox on to the launch bar, because there is no Firefox icon in the Installed Applications list under Application Launch Bar Settings.  I am aware of the related question 58383 ("Newly installed applications not available in certain PIXEL dialogs"), but at the time of posting that question has no answer.

I can get at Firefox through Menu/Internet, but a panel icon would be so much more convenient.

Comment: Right click the panel and go to settings and add it yourself. Not in front of mine ATM so might be labeled differently. There's also an lxde-panel.conf, again may be named differently, that you can manually edit and add items

Comment: @ElefantPhace, I've tried all ways of adding Firefox from the GUI, and it's never in the list of icons representing apps which can be added. I've tried manually editing the relevant config file, and this doesn't work either. Anybody know what to try next?

Comment: Edit your question to show what you've tried. Show what you added to the config file and we can help you from there. I assure you, it does indeed work